# Simplifying the Pauli matrix expression $e^{-i\sigma_x\phi/2}$

Tags: matrices, exponential-function

As in the title, the expression is:

$$e^{-i \sigma_x \phi/2}$$

Where $\sigma_x$ is:

$$\left\{ \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right\}$$

Where would I even begin in simplifying this?

Comment: Diagonalize the matrix. Do you see how this helps?

Comment: As an alternative to diagonalization, treat this like a Taylor series expansion. What do the matrices $\sigma_x^2,\sigma_x^3,\ldots$ look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have: $\sigma_{x}^2 = I$, so $\sigma_{x}^{2n} = I$ and $\sigma_{x}^{2n+1} = \sigma_{x}$. 
Then power series:
\begin{align}
\exp(-i\phi\sigma_{x}/2)) 
&= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-i\phi/2)^{k} \sigma_{x}^{k}}{k!} \\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-i\phi/2)^{2k} \sigma_{x}^{2k}}{(2k)!} + \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-i\phi/2)^{2k+1} \sigma_{x}^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}   \\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}(\phi/2)^{2k}}{(2k)!} I - i\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}(\phi/2)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} \sigma_{x} 
\end{align}
These power series are pretty well known . . .